# Javascript includes() is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML/JS where I parse DOM elements and try to find the missing ones and delete them. However, it says: `includes()` is not a function. When I execute this, I get type Object for `newHTML` and `newHTMLO` (newHTMLO is just a experimental variable). I tried `Array.from()` and `Object.valueOf()`, both producing the same result.

Can someone help me to get this working?

```
var deleteLinks = $(".remove-button .remove-from-cart");
console.log("registered: " + deleteLinks.length);
deleteLinks.on('click', function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    console.log("registered: " + deleteLinks);
    var currentHTML = $('.product');
    var currentText = $('.product .product-details .name-header');  
    var newHTML ;
    var deleteIndices = [];
        $.ajax({
        url: this.href,
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "html",
          success: function(data) {
              newHTMLO = $(data).find('.product .product-details .name-header').map(function() { return this.innerText.toUpperCase(); });   
              newHTML = Object.values(newHTMLO);
              for(i = 0; i  < newHTML.length; i++){
                  console.log(i);
                  console.log(newHTML[i]);
                  console.log(typeof newHTML);
                  console.log(typeof newHTMLO);
                  if (!(newHTML.includes(currentText[i].innerText.toUpperCase()))) {
                console.log("found mismatch for index " + i);
                deleteIndices.push(i);
                  }
              }
          }
    });

   for(i = 0; i < deleteIndices.length; i++) {
    console.log("removing " + deleteIndices[i]);
    currentHTML[deleteIndices[i]].remove();
}
});
```

Comment: `includes()` is not supported in IE. You also need a `get()` call after `map()`

Comment: The method `includes` is only defined for [Array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) and [String](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes)

Comment: I know that includes is not defined for object. When I use get and join, I get an array of each character of the innerText

Comment: `I know that includes is not defined for object.` in which case you already have you answer.

Comment: Then you did not understand the question

Comment: I tried to replicate your issue, but I could not replicate it, even with funky parameters of 'includes()'. It looks solid. Could it be that the error only happens after a few cycles of your 'for' loop? Or does it happen right away on first call of 'includes'? Just as a side note: the other comments are plain 'out of scope' when looking at the code in more detail.

Comment: @ItFreak People are trying to help you.  If they don't understand the question then you need to make it clearer, so that they do, otherwise how can they help?

Comment: If you know that includes is not defined for an object then why did you use it on an object? As for people not understanding "the question"...the question was "can you get it working?"...that's easy enough to comprehend on its own, but it's too vague. We can't suggest how to change the code without more info about what you want to do. You say you want to " try to find the missing ones and delete them"...but how can you find something if it's missing? By definition, it's not there to find. We'll need an example, and more detail about the intent of the problematic lines of code, in particular.

Comment: @ADyson I do not understand your comment. He is not using it on an object.

Comment: @PeterBranforn I was referring to the earlier comments where this was implied, and the question text where it says "When I execute this, I get type Object for newHTML". However, I take your point that, looking it the code, it would appear that it ought to be an array. It's also still true IMO that the intent of the code is unclear. And now it appears that the code doesn't necessarily match up with the reported error message, and therefore suggesting a fix is going to be tricky.

Comment: @ADyson I see what you are saying. You are right here, but I do not agree with the 'way' people answer this: Something that is obvious to others is not obvious to people that ask (that is why they ask). If you see the first comment, it does not explain the thinking behind it at all.... .

Comment: @PeterBranforn true but these are only the comments, people can make suggestions or ask for clarification. They don't have to post a fully-reasoned solution or argument, as they would they wrote in the Answers section.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I *think* the problem you have is that you're treating a jQuery object array as a regular object array, which it is not.

Change this one line and see if it resolves your problem...

```
newHTMLO = $(data)
    .find('.product .product-details .name-header')
    .toArray()    // converts a jQuery object array to a regular array
    .map(function() { return this.innerText.toUpperCase(); });
```

If that doesn't help then I'll remove this as not relevant.

Here's an example.  Map1 is your current method and map2 is the modified version...

```js
var divs = $("body").find("div");

var map1 = divs.map(function(d) { return d.innerText; });
var map2 = divs.toArray().map(function(d) { return d.innerText; });

console.log("map1: " + map1)
console.log("map2: " + map2);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>div #1</div>
<div>div #2</div>
<div>div #3</div>
<div>div #4</div>
```

Comment: Sounds reasonable! Why did I did not catch this? :P.

Comment: @PeterBranforn It's too small to spot, unless it's haunted you in the past :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was what I searched for. Didn't found while researching that I retrieved a jQuery object

Comment: No problem - glad I could help.  It was an easy thing to miss but I bet it'll never stop you again :)

Comment: Yea as a Java developer it's pretty new to have no real "types" :D

Comment: Just wait till you get used to it.  I miss it in other languages :D